# Email Token Expiring After 15 mins - Asp Identity 2.0 API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm facing a strange issue in Asp Dot Net Identity API 2.0 API.

When an user signs up, I send a confirmation email to the user. And if the user confirms his / her account within 15 mins of signing up, the "ConfirmEmailAsync" method seems to be working.

But after 15 mins, if I try to confirm the email address, I'm getting a "Invalid Token" error.

Is there a way to set the token expiry time?

A really frustrating issue and it's becoming very hard to troubleshoot.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Change the code in the Create method(App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs file).

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
 {
    manager.UserTokenProvider =
       new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
          (dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
          {                    
             TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
          };
 }
```

source: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: Thanks, this with a combination of this -> http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-and-cryptographicexception-when-running-your-site-on-microsoft-azure-web-sites/#comment-1640502238 solved my issue..

Comment: The Create method is on the ApplicationUserManager, or whatever your class is called that inherits from UserManager.

Comment: How can we make multiple purposes expire with different expiration times?