# Shorter Email Token - Asp Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I need to create an emailtoken for authentication. Using the default functionality is not an option as the emailtoken expires rather quick.

Using following code I managed to extend the tokenlifetime, but this generates a very long and complex token. Is it possible to generate a six digits token with an extended lifetime?

```
var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.DataProtectionProvider.Create("My Asp.Net Identity");
userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>(dataProtector)
{
    TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
};
```

Source:
[Email Token Expiring After 15 mins - Asp Identity 2.0 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152612/email-token-expiring-after-15-mins-asp-identity-2-0-api)

Kind Regards,

Brecht

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Just implement `IUserTokenProvider` and you can write your own logic!

```
public class CustomUserTokenProvider : IUserTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager,
        ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return
            //logic to generate code
    }

    public Task<bool> IsValidProviderForUserAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task NotifyAsync(string token, UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager,
        ApplicationUser user)
    {
        //logic to validate code
    }
}
```

Comment: And so you used .AddScoped<IUserTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>, CustomUserTokenProvider > to replace the default provider with your own ?