# Email token expired and "Email already taken" issue - Asp.net Identity 2.0 API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I'm facing a strange issue in Asp.Net Identity API 2.0.

When an user signs up, I send a confirmation email to the user, and if the user confirms his / her account within 3 hours of signing up, the "ConfirmEmailAsync" method seems to be working.

But after 3 hours, if I try to confirm the email address, I'm getting a "Invalid Token" error.

Then if the user tries to register again he gets a "Email/Name is already taken" error.

How can I solve that case that the user is getting "locked", he can't log in and he also can't register from scratch.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: This is possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152612/email-token-expiring-after-15-mins-asp-identity-2-0-api

Comment: @GauravKP The issue there is totally different. The op asks there how to change the expiration time, I'm asking how to avoid a case that the user can't sign up and also can't register because he is already in the system but without confirming his email because it expired.

Comment: To handle such deadlock, you have to give option to resend confirmation link (provided email and password is validated), with new token. As you had mentioned you can change expiration time, but we should not make it too long. Also note that in real time, email sending can also fail

Comment: why dont you generate  a new token and resend the email?

Comment: @tmg I think it's a good idea but I'm not sure at which point I would do it, when the user reaches the expired link? I'm also not sure how to do it.

Comment: if user tries to register and exists but not email confirmed, resend email with new token and replace the error message with a proper one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various places where you can do this.Say you are doing something like below to register the user

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.RegisterEmail.ToLower(), Email = model.RegisterEmail.ToLower(), PhoneNumber = model.RegisterPhoneNumber, EmailConfirmed = true, PhoneNumberConfirmed = true };
var addUserResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.RegisterPassword);


if (!addUserResult.Succeeded)
{
    ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.RegisterEmail.ToLower());
    if(!user.EmailConfirmed)
    {
       var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
       //Send the new link
       //return the error message accordingly.
    }       
}
```

You can do samething during Login

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName.ToLower(), model.Password);   
if(user != null && !user.EmailConfirmed)
{
       var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
    //Send the new link
    //return the error message accordingly.
}
```

Or if you are using SigninManager (this is from default MVC template)

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        //redirecting to a different page
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
}
```

Hope this helps.